# Install4j : Set Path system variable when the media installer is finished

Tags: install4j

I want to run a script or an action that could set Path system variable of windows when my media installer generated by Install4j is finished. But i don't find more informations to do it in the Install4j official documentation.

So how can i do that using the install4j?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an "Modify an environment variable on Windows" action. Set its "Modification type" property to "append" and the "Variable name" property to "Path".